# Scraping Data - Next Review Page

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am working on a course project and am looking to load reviews of a few products. I used the following code (thanks to other stack overflow questions).

The web scraping data when loaded doesn't give me the complete data.

The product link -

https://www.lazada.sg/products/the-rewilding-houseplant-aroid-potting-mix-soil-5l-i1304070589-s5439710559.html?spm=a2o42.home.just4u.2.654346b5QPl9bG&scm=1007.17519.162103.0&pvid=7a914f78-55e5-4469-a436-773e5ca485fb&search=0&clickTrackInfo=tcExpIds%3A244%3Btcsceneid%3AHPJFY%3Bbuyernid%3Aece30535-bc49-45a2-aced-70c0b6810838%3Btcbid%3A1%3Btcboost%3A0%3Bpvid%3A7a914f78-55e5-4469-a436-773e5ca485fb%3Bchannel_id%3A0000%3Bmt%3Ahot%3Bitem_id%3A1304070589%3Bself_ab_id%3A162103%3Bself_app_id%3A7519%3Blayer_buckets%3A955.7330_955.7331%3B

```
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script',type = 'application/ld+json').text)
data
```

The soup information downloaded does not give me the information regarding the next review button and as a result, I am not able to click on the button.

I tried the following - it worked once but sometimes gives me an error.

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.next-pagination-item.next[disabled]"))>0:
    print('done')
else:
    button_next=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.next-pagination-item.next")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_next)
    print("next page")
    time.sleep(2)
```

The above code shows the following error -

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yBVm.png)

Would appreciate any help or please do let me know if there's any additional information required. Thanks.

EDIT 1 -

Based on the comments (I had the wrong CSS selector) I revised my answer. I am seeking the class name given below - the last one should be the one selected since it says 'next'

[class names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJmTD.png)

I tried the below one but it says it can't be found but as you can see in the picture above it does exist. Also, the soup content doesn't contain this.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('next-icon next-icon-arrow-right next-icon-medium next-icon-last')
```

It responds with an error that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are you using execue_script, instead of clicking the button through the driver? Also, are you sure that the button exists on failing pages?

Comment: So I used this earlier -
`button_next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"next-icon next-icon-arrow-right next-icon-medium next-icon-last")`

but it returned "Message: no such element" But it does exist and I can't find it in the soup either.

Comment: And I believe the code posted in the question fails because of a TimeoutException (image attached) issue rather than the fact that it doesn't exist. I am still new to this please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The behavior is correct, `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` raises an exception after 10 seconds. Your css selector doesn't succeed so the exception is thrown. After failure you should inspect the next button to check the css selector is correct. Alternatively  you can use an xpath selector.

Comment: @nike.96 where is the next button you are trying to click? I can't find it physically or with your selector on the page you linked.

Comment: Hi, just revised my question - thank you for your comments! hope this is better

Comment: you don't show the error message. The image is of html.